# Image send issue to Server

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on an app. i want to send image to server but my parsing not call and not get any response.i try following code.

```
-(void)callParsing   
{

NSData *imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cameraImageView.image,0.5);


    NSLog(@"%@",imgData);

    NSString *regestrationString=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://humsomething.netsmartz.us/HumServices.svc/updateimage/vchImage=%@",imgData];

    NSURLRequest *regestrationRequest=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:regestrationString]];

    NSURLResponse *regestrationResponce;

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableData *regestrationData=[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:regestrationRequest returningResponse:&regestrationResponce error:&error]];

    //[self performXML:regestrationData];
    results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:regestrationData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];

    if([xmlParser parse])
    {
        NSLog(@"Sucessful");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict

{           

    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"RegisterUserResult"] )
    {
            if(!soapResults)
            {
                soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];   
            }
            [soapResults setString:@""];
            recordResults = TRUE;
        }       
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{       
    if( recordResults )
    {
        [soapResults appendString:string];
        NSLog(@"%@",soapResults);
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"RegisterUserResult"])
    {
        [results addObject:soapResults];
          NSLog(@" REPONSE %@",results);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more details like what action invokes callParser()?

Comment: there is all code you saw that line

Comment: if([xmlParser parse])
    {
        NSLog(@"Sucessful");
    }
this line call parser but its result failure

Answer (score 0):

I'm using following as a Uploader of my data.

```
    -(void) Uploader:(NSData *) imageData fileName : (NSString *) Name
{

    NSLog(@"%d",[imageData length]);

    NSString *urlString = @".aspx URL";

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    /*
     add some header info now
     we always need a boundary when we post a file
     also we need to set the content type

     You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same 
     as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
     */

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*
     now lets create the body of the post
     */
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",Name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];


    // now lets make the connection to the web
    //NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    //NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    theConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

    uploadedData = 0.00;
    totalData = [imageData length];


}
```